# Combine sequence values

Tags: rxjs

Suppose I have the following sequence A

```
  {a:0}        {b:1}        {c:2}
----o------------o------------o---------    [A]


  {a:0}      {a:0, b:1}   {a:0, b:1, c:2}
----o------------o------------o----------   [B]
```

how to combine values from sequence [A] to achieve the result in [B]?

I tried combineLatest() operator but it didn't work.

I need to combine the previous values each time a new values emitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) to aggregate an object's properties.

```js
const {of} = rxjs;
const {scan} = rxjs.operators;
   
of({a:0}, {b:1}, {c:2}).pipe(
    scan((acc, next) => ({...next, ...acc}), {})
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.x/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

You can change the order of `({...next, ...acc})` to `({...acc, ...next})` if you want previous values to overwrite or if you want aggregated values to overwrite.